# How to blit a list containing random x, y, images

Tags: python, list, pygame

I have this list of `particles` containing 30 images of random `x`, `y`, and `image`.
I've tried blitting it but it doesn't really work. I'm not sure how to go on about it.

```
particle = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3']
part = 30
particles = []
rand_image = random.choice(particle)
for i in range(parta):
    par = (random.randrange(w-100, w-10), random.randrange(10, h-10), rand_image)
    particles.append(par)

for particle in particles:
    win.blit(particle)
```

Comment: What did you try to blit them? Be more specific than "doesn't really work".

Comment: well, this list does works, but i just want to know how to blit this list "particles"

Comment: You need to supply more details and include your own attempt to do it: [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`particle` is a tuple with 3 components, the x and y coordinates and the image. However the arguments of [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) are the source *Surface* (iamge) and a tuple with the x and y coordinate:

```py
for particle in particles:
    win.blit(particle[2], (particle[0], particle[1]))
```

Or more comprehensible

```py
for x, y, surf in particles:
    win.blit(surf, (x, y))
```